# how to scroll two div at some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

i want to scroll on div green at some time scrolling red div
possible that by jQuery or pure javascript ????

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <p>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
        <p>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>


    </p>
          <div class="childDiv">
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        v
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y1byh25d/6/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/y1byh25d/7/

Comment: Yes ;D thank you
http://jsfiddle.net/y1byh25d/8/

Comment: You're welcome. Wasn't sure if that's what you were asking. Submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to monitor the `scroll` event of the element you're scrolling in, then you can take the `scrollTop` value and apply it to the div you want to scroll along with it.

Here's how you would do it in jquery.

```js
$('.childDiv').on('scroll',function() {
 $('.parentDiv').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
})
```

```css
.parentDiv
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.parentDiv::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

.childDiv
{
  background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv">
    <p>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
        <p>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    <br>nothing to see here <br>
    
    
    </p>
          <div class="childDiv">
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
        v
        this should scroll only form outside and inside<br>
    </div>
</div>
```